# Using Promise.all() in which the the individual promises retry on error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, promise

I have an array of promises (request-promises) that are wrapped in another method so that they will retry 3 times if an error is caught. That part is working fine. I want to use promise.all() because I am going to have a big array of http-requests eventually. With the method I am using so far, promise.all() still calls it callback function before all retry attempts have been done. Is there a way I can wait for all retry attempts to finish before promise.all() does it's callback.

```
var http_req = require('request-promise')

function My_Http(retries, options)
{
    return http_req(options)
            .then(data=>{console.log('success')})
            .catch(err => {
                retries > 0 ? My_Http(retries-1, options) :  console.log(err.message)
             })
}

var promises = []
promises.push( My_Http(3, options1))
promises.push( My_Http(3, options2))

promise.all(promises).then( data=> {console.log(data)} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think this was a dumb mistake but might be good for others to see, I removed the then inside My_Http and return the entire ternary statement.

```
var http_req = require('request-promise')

function My_Http(retries, options)
{
    return http_req(options)
            .catch(err => {
                return retries > 0 ? My_Http(retries-1, options) :  console.log(err.message)
             })
}

var promises = []
promises.push( My_Http(3, options1))
promises.push( My_Http(3, options2))

promise.all(promises).then( data=> {console.log(data)} )
```

Comment: Yep, you have to return the retried promise in order to chain it appropriately.  The `.then()` was not preventing retry, it was just stopping you from getting the return value because you didn't return the value from the `.then()`.

Comment: note: the then block was fine, it's the return in your catch block that makes the difference

Comment: Prefer `.map` and not `.push`.